# How is the ankylosaurus animal companion's stun DC calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, animal-companions, difficulty-class

So in my last question, [Dinosaur Damage Dilemma](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137883/how-do-i-increase-the-damage-of-an-ankylosaurus-companion-s-tail-without-reducin), I was talking about damage for an [Ankylosaurus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dinosaur/ankylosaurus/) and I realised that while the dinosaur can stun, the DC would be different for an animal companion. It says it is Strength Based, but I did the maths and that didn't make sense.

So the question is, how is and Ankylosaurus's Stun DC calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ignore the bestiary entry

And that's a tip about *all* animal companions. Each companion have their own rules, which are mostly different from the bestiary entry for that same creature.

For the [ankylosaurus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/#Ankylosaurus), this is how the ability actually reads:

> **Stun (Ex)**
>
> The ankylosaurus’s tail can deliver a powerful, stunning blow. A creature struck by this attack must make a DC (**10 + 1/2 HD + Str modifier**) Fortitude save or be dazed for 1 round. If the strike is a critical hit and the target fails its save, it is instead stunned for 1d4 rounds.